# awk to read specific column from a file

Tags: awk

I have a small problem and I would appreciate helping me in it.

In summary, I have a file:

```
1,5,6,7,8,9

2,3,8,5,35,3

2,46,76,98,9
```

I need to read specific lines from it and print them into another text document. I know I can use (`awk '{print "$2" "$3"}'`) to print the second and third columns beside each other. However, I need to use two statement as (`awk '{print "$2"}' >> file.text`) then (`awk '{print "$3"}' >> file.text`), but the two columns would appear under each other and not beside each other.

How can I make them appear beside each other?

Comment: Why do you need to use two statements?

Comment: I donno why you are using awk '{print "$2"}' >> file.text instead of awk '{print $2,$3}' >> file.text

Comment: Do not quote the field reference: `awk '{print "$2"}'` will give you the characters `$` and `2`, not the value of the second column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *must* extract the columns in separate processes, use [`paste`](http://man.cx/paste) to stitch them together. I assume your shell is bash/zsh/ksh, and I assume the blank lines in your sample input should not be there.

```
paste -d, <(awk -F, '{print $2}' file) <(awk -F, '{print $3}' file)
```

produces

```
5,6
3,8
46,76
```

Without the process substitutions:

```
awk -F, '{print $2}' file > tmp1
awk -F, '{print $3}' file > tmp2
paste -d, tmp1 tmp2 > output
```

---

Update based on your answer:

On first appearance, that's a confusing setup. Does this work?

```
for (( x=1; x<=$number_of_features; x++ )); do
    feature_number=$(sed -n "$x {p;q}" feature.txt)
    if [[ -f out.txt ]]; then
        cut -d, -f$feature_number file.txt > out.txt
    else
        paste -d, out.txt <(cut -d, -f$feature_number file.txt) > tmp &&
        mv tmp out.txt
    fi
done
```

That has to read the file.txt file a number of times. It would clearly be more efficient to only have to read it once:

```
awk -F, -f numfeat=$number_of_features '
    # read the feature file into an array
    NR==FNR {
        colno[++i] = $0
        next
    }

    # now, process the file.txt and emit the desired columns
    {
        sep = ""
        for (i=1; i<=numfeat; i++) {
            printf "%s%s", sep, $(colno[i])
            sep = FS
        }
        print ""
    }
' feature.txt file.txt > out.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Glenn for the quick response!

I will try it and get back to you
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for contributing in the answers. I believe that i should be more clearer in my question, sorry for that.

My code is as follow:

```
for (( x = 1; x <= $number_of_features ; x++ )) # the number extracted from a text file
do
    feature_number=$(awk 'FNR == "'$x'" {print}' feature.txt)
    awk -F, '{print $"'$feature_number'"}' file.txt >> out.txt
done
```

Basically, I extract the feature number (which is the same as column number) from a text document and then print that column. the text document may contains many features number.

The thing is, each time I have different features number (which reflect the column number). so, applying the above solutions are not sufficient for this problem.

I hope it is clearer now.

Waiting for your comments please.

Thanks
Ahmad

Comment: You should edit your question with this information, not provide it as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

instead of using awks file redirection, use shell redirection eg

```
awk '{print $2,$3}' >> file
```

the comma is replaced with the value of the output field seperator( space by default ).