# Use mapfile and awk in the same command

Tags: linux, awk

I'm trying to map a file to a variable and take from it only the part after a '/'

For now I have this:

```
mapfile VAR < path_to_file
echo $VAR | awk -F '/' '{ print $2 }'
```

How to combine those two commands into one? I can't find any examples.

Comment: `awk -F '/' '{ print $2 }' path_to_file` , you can't do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [awk to read specific column from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14337104/608639) and [Take nth column in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17137269/608639). Lots of examples of using awk and reading from a file: [awk read from file](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=awk+read+from+file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
awk -F '/' '{ print $2 }' path_to_file
```

what you do is actually same as

```
mapfile VAR < test.txt && echo $VAR | awk -F '/' '{ print $2 }'
```